# Parallel version of K-Means clustering in R?

Tags: r, k-means

I have a dataset containing 200,000 observations and three dimensions.  I'm trying to discover the optimal number of clusters via the Elbow method like so:

```
library(cluster)    # clustering algorithms
library(factoextra) # clustering algorithms & visualization
set.seed(123)
fviz_nbclust(df, kmeans, method = "wss")
```

However, given the size of my dataset, it appears this this method does not yield after over an hour.  I have been looking for parallel version of KMeans that will identify the "optimal" number of clusters, but to no avail.  What is the best way of running K-means on big data?

Comment: Take a look at [this question and my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55341728/how-to-reduce-memory-usage-within-prados-k-means-framework-used-on-big-data-in).

Comment: Thanks @Alexis.  Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, k-means is fast relatively. ([clustering method performance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-cluster-comparison-py)) I experienced to stay initialize phase, even after a long time. I learned in case of k-means, if the initial points is not set up properly, it is known that unstable clustering results are learned.(You must google k-means Initialization issues) If similar points is selected for initial points, the learning result, as well as performance, is not good. I want to tell you it's important to find initial points(a wide spread).

Comment: Seems like the link you sent is referencing "mini-batch k means", which is different from the standard algorithm.  But perhaps I should be using that... In any case, I'm trying to find a non-memory intensive K-means algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Try the h2o R package.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/index.html

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/k-means.html

The H2O-3 is open-source Machine Learning platform. H2O’s core code is written in Java. Inside H2O, a Distributed Key/Value store is used to access and reference data, models, objects, etc., across all nodes and machines. The algorithms are implemented on top of H2O’s distributed Map/Reduce framework and utilize the Java Fork/Join framework for multi-threading. The data is read in parallel and is distributed across the cluster and stored in memory in a columnar format in a compressed way. H2O’s REST API allows access to all the capabilities of H2O from an external program or script via JSON over HTTP. The Rest API is used by H2O’s web interface (Flow UI), R binding (H2O-R), and Python binding (H2O-Python).